# How to prevent two filters from overwriting each other on my website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-api

Desperately need help with my js code

So basically I have been trying to resolve this problem for more than 15! hours. I know that it shouldn't be that hard, but still here I am. I tried to do it a lot of ways but failed. If you help me correct my code i would be forever grateful because im starting to lose my sanity.
So basically I have 2 filters on website. First filter - buttons where i can select genders Second - job Type

```
  typeOfGender.forEach((li) => {
    li.addEventListener("click", () => {
      li.classList.toggle("filter-header-selected");
      removeJob2();
    });
  });
  typeOfWork.forEach((li) => {
    li.addEventListener("click", () => {
      li.classList.toggle("filter-footer-selected");
      removeJob();
    });
  });
```

So i toggle class there to know what is selected. Nothing wrong so far.

```
  function removeJob() {
    let CheckedJobs = [];
    let difference = [];
    //type of work
    document.querySelectorAll(".filter-footer-selected p").forEach((pHtml) => {
      arrayOfClickableJobs.forEach((job) => {
        if (pHtml.innerHTML == job[1]) CheckedJobs.push(job);
      });
      difference = arrayOfClickableJobs.filter(
        (element) => !CheckedJobs.includes(element)
      );
    });
    //
    CheckedJobs.forEach((x) => {
      x[0].setVisible(true);
    });
    difference.forEach((x) => {
      x[0].setVisible(false);
    });
    if (difference.length === 0) {
      arrayOfClickableJobs.forEach((x) => {
        x[0].setVisible(true);
      });
    }
  }
  function removeJob2() {
    let CheckedJobs = [];
    let difference = [];
    //type of work
    document.querySelectorAll(".filter-header-selected").forEach((pHtml) => {
      arrayOfClickableJobs.forEach((job) => {
        if (job[2].includes(pHtml.innerHTML.match(/[А-Яа-я]/)[0].toLowerCase()))
          CheckedJobs.push(job);
      });
      difference = arrayOfClickableJobs.filter(
        (element) => !CheckedJobs.includes(element)
      );
    });

    //
    CheckedJobs.forEach((x) => {
      x[0].setVisible(true);
    });
    difference.forEach((x) => {
      x[0].setVisible(false);
    });
    if (difference.length === 0) {
      arrayOfClickableJobs.forEach((x) => {
        x[0].setVisible(true);
      });
    }
  }
```

arrayOfClickableJobs - is array of all jobs on website. This 2 functions basically the same. I create array of selected buttons Than I iterate through them and iterate through all the jobs to find a match and push matched jobs in CheckedJobs array.
difference - is opposite of CheckedJobs, it has all the job that is not the match. Than as you can see i show all the jobs i selected and hide other. If I use only one filter - this code works perfectly fine, but if I use two it breaks. If i want to find Women - it will show every women and hide everything. But if select Women and than select in another filter teacher - it will show all teachers regardless of gender - second filter that i use overwrite first. I would be very grateful If someone helped me with this. I wasted a lot of time on this code but cant figure out how to connect this two filters...

Comment: would be helpful if you included all your revelant code, create a snippet to reproduce the problem including your HTML. `typeOfGender` for example is undefined and it will make things more dificult if we can't see the whole revelant code

Comment: I tried but the jobs is in google maps (google map api) and jsfiddle or codepen does not load it. Its just a blank screen without job pins... Can you tell me from my description at least few ideas that i can try